# python dictionaries, read file lines, add to dict()

Tags: python, function, file, dictionary

this needs to read from a text file .txt, read the file add to a dictionary so user can later search, add/remove key and values. it does ask for the file name but after being handed the file it crashes with a trace back to contact[x[0] = y[1] out of index.

load file

```
def fileload(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as file:
        contact={}
        for line in file:
            x = line.replace(",","")
            y=x.split(':')
            contact[x[0]] = y[1]
            print('this is x value',x)

    return contact
```

ask user for file name, ask user who to search for, asks user what to add/remove/change(update)

```
  def main():
    print('To search through names and emails first select the file')
    filename=input('Whats the name of the .txt file?(Please add .txt) :  ')
    search=fileload(filename)

    try:
        search=fileload(filename)
    except:
        print("Sory file not found try again!")

    contact=fileload(filename)
    print('\n----Would you like to search up an email by name?----')
    name_search=input('Whats the person called?: ')
```

try to look for name, try to look for user input then modify user input per user request

```
   for key,value in contact:
        if name_search == value:
            print(f'{name_search} is here!')

        else:
            print(f"{name_search} is not here!")
    print('Would you like to add/remove a name or email?')
    modify=input.lower("i would like to (remove or add)")
    try:
        if  modify  != remove or add:
            print("Sorry you can only choose remove or add!")
    except:
        if modify == remove:
            modify== remove
        if modify == add:
            modify=add

    modify_detail=input.lower(f"would you like to {modify} an email or name?: ")

    try:
        if modify_detail == name:
            modify_detail== name
        if modify_detail == email:
            modify_detail == email

    except:
        if modify  != email or name:
            print(f"please choose a name or email to {modify} ")
            modify_detail=input.lower(f"please pick if you want to {modify} name or email!: ")

    if modify == remove:
        if modify_detail== name:
            print("Pick a name that you want to remove")
            name_remove=input('what name do you want to remove?')
            del contact.get[name_remove]
        if modify_detail == email:
            print("Pick an email to remove or c")
            email_remove=input("what email will you be removing?")
            del contact.get[email_remove]
        print(contact)

    if modify == add:
        if modify_detail == name:
            print("Whats the name that you will be addind?")
            new_name=input("whats the new name?")
            contact["name"]=new_name
        if modify_detail == email:
            print("whats the new email?")
            new_email=input('new email:  ')
            contact["email"]=new_email
            print(contact)



main()
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Most of this is totally irrelevant. If you are getting an IndexError, you **really** need to do some minimal debugging before even posting a question here, and come to us with those results if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: im new to python. this is like my first real month getting into it, im pretty bad at using functions and having values from functions passed around to other functions. but i cant get contact dictionary to get any values or key. adding print statements to see where it does hold a value just breaks it more. so im really at the end of my knowledge base sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Again, **you need to provide a [mcve]**. A simple thing would just be to `print(line)` to see what's actually being processed on each iteration.

Comment: so i started tinkering with it, changed contact[x[0]] = y[1] to y[-1] this gives me the whole line. but still does not split the line (which is formatted as: (full name) , (email) ) also added contact['name']=x
            contact['email']=y
but i havent been able to get it to split into two values then save each value under a key with said value being assigned as the key's value. also when user inputs name value for any name in list it returns that its not there. error promt says nameError "remove" is not defined

Comment: i can only get it to grab a single letter from the line, as well it proceeds to the next blocks of code where it searches the dictionary for  value under email key or name key it returns negative always. also the name error im not even sure what to do with

Answer (score 0):

The only reason can be there is no **:** in your file's at least one line. Maybe you hit at the end of the file. Most files in *nix systems ends with an empty line.

For example:

```
a:a:a\n
b:b:b\n
\n
```

like this:

```
def fileload(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as file:
        contact={}
        for line in file.read().split("\n"):
            if ":" in line:
                x = line.replace(",","")
                y=x.split(':')
                contact[x[0]] = y[1]
                print('this is x value',x)

    return contact
```

Comment: ive tried that switched the example file to a comma and in the source file i just forgot to change it here.

Comment: the example file im working with: (persons full name), (email address) and holds 20 lines as such so my dictionary in python should looke like contact={[name]:____ , [email]:____

Comment: try to count lines in your code, you can see 20 lines in an editor but there can be 21 lines especially in linux produced files. the last one can be the example that i have gave at top

Comment: i tinkered around with it and i was able to get it to some what work. but now it only holds one letter